# Object construction with validation in Scala, using that in an Anorm parser

Tags: scala, anorm

I have a simple case class Amount as below

```
case class Amount(value: Long, currency: Currency)
```

And an accompanying object to convert a string currency code into a Currency object

```
object Amount {
  private val log = Logger(getClass)
  def apply(value: Long, currencyCode: String) : Amount = {
    try {
      Amount(value, Currency.getInstance(currencyCode))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        log.error(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
        throw new Exception(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
    }
  }
}
```

Invocation :

```
val amount : Amount = Amount(1234, "USD")
```

When I read some data from the database, I have a custom parser such as

```
implicit val amountParser = Macro.parser[Amount]("value", "currencyCode")
```

However, the compiler complains

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: value apply encapsulates multiple overloaded alternatives and cannot be treated as a method. Consider invoking `<offending symbol>.asTerm.alternatives` and manually picking the required method
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asMethod(Symbols.scala:228)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asMethod(Symbols.scala:84)
[error]     at anorm.Macro$.parserImpl(Macro.scala:70)
[error]     at anorm.Macro$.namedParserImpl_(Macro.scala:25)
[error]     implicit val amountParser = Macro.parser[Amount]("value", "currencyCode")
```

How do I make this work ?

**UPDATE**

After understanding the response from @MikeAllen, I decided to leave the `case class Amount` and the `object Amount` as is, instead I wrote a custom parser for the Amount as below

```
    implicit private val amountParser = for {
        value <- long("value")
        currencyCode <- str("currency_code")
      } yield { 
           Amount(value, currencyCode) 
      }
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? Did I miss anything, or do you have any further questions?

Comment: Your response was very helpful. Thank you. I updated my post above to include the changes I made.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Your solution is very elegant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Scala* compiler will automatically generate an `Amount.apply` factory method for creating `case class` instances, which is why you're getting this error - because you have multiple `Amount.apply` methods. One of these takes arguments of type (`Long`, `Currency`) and the other takes arguments of type (`Long`, `String`). The error message suggests that you need to select one of these from the overloaded alternatives reported through *reflection*.

Alternatively, your case class and companion might be reworked as follows:

```
final case class Amount(value: Long, currencyCode: String) {

  /** Currency. Will create an exception on instantiation if code is invalid. */
  val currency: Currency = {
    try {
      Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        Amount.log.error(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
        throw new Exception(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
    }
  }
}

object Amount {
  private val log = Logger(getClass)
}
```

This is not quite as elegant, admittedly, as you now have a field, `currency`, that isn't one of the case class's parameters and that isn't available for pattern matching, while also carrying around the string form.

A better solution would be to keep your original `case class` and convert the currency code field from a `String` into a `Currency`, before creating the `Amount` instance, as part of the parser:

```
val amountMapping = {
  get[Long]("value") ~ get[String]("currencyCode") map {
    case value ~ currencyCode => {
      val currency = {
        try {
          Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception =>
            Amount.log.error(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
            throw new Exception(s"Invalid currency code [$currencyCode]")
        }
      }
      Amount(value, currency)
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use this to parse rows, for example with:

```
def amounts(): List[Amount] = SQL("select * from amounts").as(amountMapping *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I ended up leaving the class and objects as is and re-wrote the amount parser.

`implicit private val amountParser = for {
    value <- long("amount")
    currencyCode <- str("currency_code")
  } yield { Amount(value,currencyCode) }`